# Flash trace,dump,print Array variables

Tags: arrays, flash

is there a way to trace an ARRAY in FLASH.

I want to have an output similar to PHPs command:`print_r(myArray)`

for ex: (in flash):

```
var event:Array = new Array();
event['name']='david';
trace(event);  // that display anything
```

while print_r(event) in PHP would display as string:

```
Array {
['name'] => david,
}
```

I want to achieve same kind of result in flash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`trace(array.join());` would work for numerically indexed arrays. For associative arrays, you have to use `for..in` construct.

```
for(var t:Object in array)
  trace(t + " : " + array[t]);
```

Comment: for(var t:Object in

the only type allowed for loop is string type.  , got error message.

Comment: `for(var t:Object in array)` works in Flex builder 3. Can you post the error message that you're getting?

Comment: `The only type allowed for a for-in loop iterator is String.`

Comment: Interesting.. are you using Flex Builder or CS3?

Comment: Flash CS4 ,  for AS2 application

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. I am on Flex Builder 3, AS3. Either `var t:String in array` or `var t:* in array` or just `var t in array` should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(event));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actionscript *trace* function (in any actionscript language versions) is pretty much a big shame.

Just try that to laugh:

```
var a :Array = [1,2,3];
var b :Array = [4,5,6, a];
a[3] = b;

trace(a);
```

A non shameful trace function should indeed loop over the array's elements and trace the arrays inside the arrays as the AS3 *trace* function does. But it should also check for circular references between inner and parent arrays inside the root array which is traced. This can be implemented in a recursive or iterative way.

If you're not agree that AS3 *trace* function is bad then also consider the fact that this function will not let you see if an array is contained inside another. I mean that this code:

```
var a :Array = [1,2,3];
var b :Array = [a, 4,5,6];

trace(b);
```

will output this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

although we could expect this kind of output:

```
[1,2,3],4,5,6
```

And finally if you have null or undefined values inside your arrays then they'll be traced as empty strings:

```
var a :Array = [1,2,undefined,3];
var b :Array = [4,5,6, null, a];

trace(b);
```

will output this:

```
4,5,6,,1,2,,3
```

**... !!! ...**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `.toString` method on `Array`?

```
trace( myArray.toString() );
```

Here are the docs reference:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#toString()

Alternatively if you are using associative arrays, then the way to trace its values would be:

```
for (var prop:String in myArray)
{
    trace( prop, " = ", myArray[prop] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function obj_size (o:Object){
    var n=0;
    for (var x in o)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

DOES WORK ;)

SO I SOLVED sizeof() evivalend to Array.sizeof();

**How ABOUT array.push() for Objects ??**

Answer (score 0):

```
trace(JSON.stringify(your_complex_variable, null, 2))
```

The number parameter is used for indentation. See https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#stringify()